# Is there a way to hide the picture when the user press "print screen" button?

Tags: javascript, php, security, web

My site (php, javascript) presenting a picture to the user. I want to protect the picture, and make it as hard as possible to get. The user can't download it, but he can use the "print screen" button.

Is there a way to hide the picture when the user press "print screen" button?

Comment: Am not sure but can you restrict the keys value to be pressed means he couldn't be able to press the key?

Comment: If the browser can display the picture the user has it already on its client.

Comment: at the moment the picture is displayed on the user screen, the picture is already on the user harddisk so you can difficultly forbid to download it - even if you try to protect it someone who really want the picture will always find someone whis the knowledge for download it

Comment: If the user can view the picture he / she can download the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because someone can simply view your website in a virtual machine and take a screenshot from the host operating system. Any answer that attempts to intercept keystrokes or clear the clipboard can easily be defeated by this approach and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: To add to this: you'll end up seriously frustrating users if you try to prevent them taking legitimate screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

## Not supported

This is not supported in web based solutions.

If you're using IE, You can try to clear the clipboard <kbd>print screen</kbd> by

```
<body onload=setInterval("window.clipboardData.setData('text','')",2) oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false">
```

but his is a bad approach.

---

If this is critical for you, consider wrap your web app with a native one that has low level hooks to cover that for you

Answer (score 0):

> The user can't download it

If the image is displaying on the screen then the browser has already downloaded it and the user can just browse to their cache and copy the file out. The best way to prevent image "piracy" is to use watermarking.